# Fullcalendar using a JSON PHP page as an event source

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to use a PHP page hosted on a MySQL server that generates a JSON feed that I want to use as in the "eventSources" array of Fullcalendar in my Ionic application. The calendar is rendering, but it isn't displaying the dates in the feed. I have been working at this for a couple of days and none of the documents on the Fullcalendar site aren't working.

Here's the JSON String:

```
 {"success":1,"message":"Details Available!","events":[
 {"ID":"1","title":"Example Class","start":"2014-08-29 09:00:00","end":"2014-08-29 17:00:00","all_day":"0"},
 {"ID":"2","title":"Example Class 2","start":"2014-08-13 00:00:00","end":"2014-08-13 00:00:00","all_day":"0"},
 {"ID":"3","title":"Example Event with Time","start":"2014-08-13 12:00:00","end":"2014-08-13 13:00:00","all_day":"0"},
 {"ID":"11","title":"Testing 123","start":"2014-08-13 00:00:00","end":"2014-08-13 23:59:00","all_day":"1"}]}
```

Here is the PHP Page generating the JSON above:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header("Content-Type:application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$user="user";
$pass="password";
$table="database";


$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$table", $user,$pass);

//initial query
$query = "Select * FROM table";

//execute query
try {
      $stmt   = $db->query($query);
     }
catch (PDOException $ex) {
      $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
      die(json_encode($response));
     }

 // Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


 if ($rows) {
     $response["success"] = 1;
     $response["message"] = "Details Available!";
     $response["events"]   = array();

 foreach ($rows as $row) {
     $post             = array();
$post["ID"]  = $row["ID"];
     $post["title"] = $row["title"];
     $post["start"]    = $row["start"];
     $post["end"]  = $row["end"];
     $post["all_day"] = $row["all_day"];

     //update our repsonse JSON data
     array_push($response["events"], $post);
    }


     // echoing JSON response
     echo json_encode($response);

   } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No Events Available!";
            die(json_encode($response));
       }

   ?>
```

Here is the the controller for the calendar:

```
App.controller('LogHomeCtrl', function($scope, $log, $state)
{
$scope.TimeTabl = function()
{
    $state.go('timetable');
}
});

App.controller('calCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $state)
{
$scope.eventSources = [
{
    events: {
        url: 'url/calendarConnect.php',
        type: 'POST',
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
        color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
        textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
    }
}

];
});
```

I have tried using different methods of calling the PHP page, but none of it is working. If someone could point out where I am going wrong that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exists few ways how you can set `events` for calendar:

1.as array:

```
events: [
    {
        title: 'Example Class',
        start: '2014-08-29 09:00:00',
        end: '2014-08-29 17:00:00'
    },
    {
        title: 'Example Class 2',
        start: '2014-08-13 00:00:00',
        end: '2014-08-13 00:00:00'
    }
]
```

2.as json object:

```
events: 'url/calendarConnect.php' //must to return json similar to previous example
```

3.as function:

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url/calendarConnect.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            //get your events from response.events
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

4.as custom function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url/calendarConnect.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        //just example
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: response.events
        });    
    }    
});
```

In your case 3-rd way is more appropriate. For more details, please, see official [Fullcalendar documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/) about events.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it has almost worked, however I am now having issues with the callback function used at the end of the documented function after the success function is explained, it keeps responding with "undefined is not a function/unknown identifier" depending on where I place it within the code.

Comment: you need to call `callback(response.events)` in the success function, it should be work. Also, you can create simple ajax function and set it response to calendar events. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: i read through the function documentations, messed around with the code until it started working, sorry about late response. I forgot to set as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this (add [] after ["events"]):

> array_push($response["events"][], $post);